# How I can move DOM elements slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How I can move DOM elements slowly?
This does not work

```
 for ( var a = 0 ; a < 100 ; a++){

    $('*').each(function(){

      if ( ! /HTML/.test($(this).context.nodeName))
      {
        var top =  parseInt($(this).css('top')) + 1;

        $(this).css('top',top + "px");
      }

    });
  }
```

Elements are positioned when the loop finish

How can I do this slowly?

Sorry for my English

Comment: There's a super-secret "slow running Javascript" John Resig keeps under his pillow... Oop! Actually, using a `setTimeout()` to mark time is how you would do it normally.

Comment: Here's a demo of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/AZJzz/4/

Comment: `setInterval()` can do the job as well

Comment: I am testing both options. Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

try jquery's [$.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

it requires you to set a target position to move to, rather than continuous movement

or using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
intervalInMilliseconds=17;//60 frames per second
var interval = setInterval(function()
{
for ( var a = 0 ; a < 100 ; a++){

    $('*').each(function(){

      if ( ! /HTML/.test($(this).context.nodeName))
      {
        var top =  parseInt($(this).css('top')) + 1;

        $(this).css('top',top + "px");
      }

    });
  }
},intervalInMilliseconds);
```

stop when you're done by doing this:

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

Comment: You should probably avoid linking to w3schools on SO; the http://w3fools.com might get you right in the downvote. `:\ `

Comment: Also, don't you eventually want to stop `setInterval()`?

Comment: Thanks for the link @JaredFarrish I've seen their bullschildt touted by the unwary before (though didn't even know until just now that they claim to offer "certification", wtf?) Good to have a quick place to link people to to warn people.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason setInterval and setTimeout works, is that the page isn't re-drawn until the javascript has finished running, so even if the js was slow enough the effect wouldn't be seen but setInterval returns control allowing the repaint and the next interval is a separate call.

Comment: @JaredFarrish store the interval `var interval = setInterval(function(){},1000)` then do this `clearInterval(interval)` when u want to stop it

Comment: You of course aren't telling *me* right? Put it in your answer.

Comment: That's very interesting.
Then the only two ways to repaint an element is using setInterval or setTimeOut?

Comment: neither setInterval nor setTimeout repaints elements

Answer (score 1):

Or in pure javascript, you should use a timer

```
var $elem = $(this), // jquery object
    elem = $elem[0], // dom element
    currentPos = $elem.offset().top, // current position
    targetPos = currentPosition + 100, // target position
    timer = setInterval (function () { // timer to move element slowly
        currentPos++;
        $elem.css('top',currentPosition + "px");
        if (currentPos == targetPos)
            clearInterval(timer);
    }, 100);
```

Comment: What? `this` and `$elem[0]` are the same. You say pure javascript, but where's the *purity*?!?! `:P`

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting new enough browser versions, you could use [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_animations) instead.